# using a bmesh changes the behaviour of other parts of the code

Tags: python, scripting, bmesh

i have some code, which moves vertices in a mesh:

```
#not working!
#translate the sign pole to ensure it is behind sign
transAmt = kvMaxY - spMinY
print (transAmt)
for v in signPoleVerts:
    loc = v.co + mathutils.Vector((0, transAmt, 0))
    v.co = loc
```

in its current state it doesnt seem to work - the position of the vertices in signPoleVerts does not change.

when i add a bmesh, it works, even when i do nothing with it:

```
dummy_bmesh = bmesh.new()
dummy_bmesh.from_mesh(sign.data)
dummy_bmesh.to_mesh(sign.data)

#now works
#translate the sign pole to ensure it is behind sign
transAmt = kvMaxY - spMinY
print (transAmt)
for v in signPoleVerts:
    loc = v.co + mathutils.Vector((0, transAmt, 0))
    v.co = loc
```

what is happening here? I would prefer not to create the bmesh for no reason...

**EDIT**
here is the code directly before the above - it defines kvMaxY, spMinY and signPoleVerts

```
#get the key vertices which will ensure pole does not poke through sign, and find max y
keyVerts = getVertsInGroup(sign, sign.vertex_groups["poleConnectionVerts"])
kvMaxY = -math.inf
print("keyverts:")
for v in keyVerts:
    print(v.co.y)
    if v.co.y > kvMaxY:
        kvMaxY = v.co.y 

#get the sign pole vertices, and find min y
signPoleVerts = getVertsInGroup(sign, sign.vertex_groups["signPole"])
spMinY = math.inf
print ("signPoleVerts:")
for v in signPoleVerts:
    print (v.co.y)
    if v.co.y < spMinY:
        spMinY = v.co.y
```

getVertsInGroup is a function defined as below:

```
def getVertsInGroup (obj, vertexGroup):
vertexGroupId = vertexGroup.index
return [vert for vert in obj.data.vertices if  vertexGroupId in [vg.group for vg in vert.groups]]
```

Comment: Please expand on the code above, in particular how you assign `signPoleVerts`

Comment: have added some more of the code :)

Comment: Suggest going one way or 'tother.  Either use `mesh.vertices` and no bmesh, or `bm.verts`   The bmesh `bm_dummy` is a snapshot of the mesh from when you from meshed it.   If you want to use a live edit (mode) mesh `bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(mesh)`

Comment: @batFINGER Hello, just to follow up, I did a bit more research on bmesh and performed the whole of my script on a bmesh rather than using bpy.ops, and that has fixed the problem. never got to the root cause of this bit of behaviour though! thanks for your help.